# cannot use classes inside another referenced project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference

I want to use classes inside 'BaseClasses' project from 'BasePackages' project. I've referenced BasePackages to BaseClasses but I can't access classes yet. a warning is showing in my reference Icon as you can see below. What should I do?

[image: my problem!]

I did reference like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Did the `BaseClasses` project compile successfully?  Is there something in `BaseClasses` that would cause a circular reference?

Comment: Also, if you mouse over the warning icon, does it give a tooltip or any indication what the problem is?

Comment: @Tim no circular references, no tooltip! why there is no tool tip :(

Comment: @Tim after building BaseClasses all is ok:  
Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped

Comment: Try doing a "Clean" on the solution and then build it again (or rebuild the solution, which will perform a clean).  If that doesn't work, try closing and opening VS again.

Comment: Done! by recreating the BaseClasses project! I think the problem was for renaming BaseClasses from It's original name. thanks for your care.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is a project reference, not an assembly reference. Make sure they are compiled for the same .NET framework versions. Otherwise do a build and observe the build output window of Visual Studio, it will tell you what's wrong.